# Ending up with multiple calls (due to cyclical referencing) - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective is fairly simple. In my webapp, I have two pages and I want to call each one from the other page.

But the way I have implemented the function calls in Javascript seems to be flawed. I have read up on `closure`, `bubbling`, `recursion` and `event.stopPropagation()`, but still not sure what the right way to go about implementing this.

Here's the smallest code that I could reproduce my problem in.

```
    function init(){
    var $div1 = 'Click to Load page 2';
    $("#main").append($div1);

    var $div2 = 'Click to go back to  page 1';
    $("#main").append($div2);    
    displayFirstPage();
}


    function displayFirstPage() {
    var $div1 = $("#div1");
    var $div2 = $("#div2");    

    $div2.hide();
    $div1.show();

    alert("first called");

    $div1.click(function(){
    displaySecondPage();
    });
}


    function displaySecondPage() {
    var $div1 = $("#div1");
    var $div2 = $("#div2");    

    alert("second called");
    $div1.hide();
    $div2.show();

    $div2.click(function(){
    displayFirstPage();
    });
}
```

After clicking the divs a few times, I end up with **numerous** alert's popping up. I just want each call to be executed once. Clearly, I am missing the way to terminate the function call.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
$div1.click(function(){
    displaySecondPage();
});
```

and

```
$div2.click(function(){
    displayFirstPage();
});
```

should be inside your `init()` function. Every time you call those you are adding another click handler to the div. You only want to add them once, so just put them in `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because you bind a new anonymous function to the click event every time the display functions are invoked.

Move the click-binding code into you init() function:

```
function init(){
    var $div1 = 'Click to Load page 2';
    $("#main").append($div1);

    var $div2 = 'Click to go back to  page 1';
    $("#main").append($div2);  

    var $div1 = $("#div1");

    $div1.click(function(){
    displaySecondPage();
    });

    var $div2 = $("#div2");

    $div2.click(function(){
    displayFirstPage();
    });    



    displayFirstPage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code, @Greg Ross. I +1'ed you and accepted Golf's answer because he was the first to respond. Regards, Ram

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason you don't want to put the `.click()` functions in your `init()` function (like [golf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081943/503550) describes), you can change each `.click()` line to `.unbind().click()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you add a new click handler every time you call

$div2.click(function)